# Python def without Indentation

Tags: python

There are multiple occurrences of following format(note there is no indentation after def lines) in a source file I have:

```
def sendSystemParms2(self, destAddress, subid, state):

raw = sysparms_format2.build(Container(
length = 0x0D,
command = MT_APP_MSG_CMD0))

def method2(parm2):
print parm2
```

and it's working and running. I am confused. Any hints?
I can't upload an image due to being new and not having enough reputations but I can show the proof.

Comment: Do these methods live inside a class? Have you tried adjusting your tab sizing to 8?

Comment: Try clearing out any `.pyc` files or the `__pycache__` folder. It may be that python is loading a cached version of the module.

Comment: Many editors (such as Atom, PyCharm, Brackets) have a 'show whitespace' option that will give you printable characters instead of non printable characters.

Comment: You are also missing a closing parenthesis after the fifth line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a file that uses a mixture of tabs and spaces.

Python expands tabs to *eight spaces*, but you are looking at the file in an editor that uses a tabstop size of *four spaces*.

The function bodies use tabs for the indentation, but the `def` lines use 4 spaces instead. As such as far as Python is concerned the method bodies are indented correctly.

If I set my text editor to using tabs with a size of 8 spaces, and then select the text to have the editor highlight tabs, I see:

<kbd>[image: source code with indentation highlighted]</kbd>

The lines indicate tabs.

This is one of the reasons you should not be using tabs for indentation *at all*. The [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) recommends you use only spaces for indentation. In Python 3, mixing tabs and spaces like this is a syntax error.

You can tell Python 2 to raise `TabError` for this mix of tabs and spaces as well, by running Python with the [`-tt` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-t):

> `-t`
>   Issue a warning when a source file mixes tabs and spaces for indentation in a way that makes it depend on the worth of a tab expressed in spaces. Issue an error when the option is given twice (*-tt*).

Comment: It's also illegal in Python 2 if you pass `-tt` to the interpreter.  This is probably a Good Idea in most circumstances.

Comment: to be fair, this particular error doesn't really mean that you should use spaces over tabs or vice versa, it just means that you need to be consistent. (fwiw, i use spaces...)